# Issue converting EntryId to EwsId, it gives ImmutableId

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm following tutorial and succesfully run the convert from EntryId to EwsId, using either EWS or GraphAPI (result is the same).

But the problem is that while I can convert from EntryId to RestId and find it back with Graph, converting from EntryId to EwsId and then Binding gives the error **"This protocol does not support ImmutableIds"**.

```
$64decoded = [System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ItemId)).Replace("-", "")
        write-host $64decoded
        $HexId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AlternateId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::HexEntryId, $64decoded, $email)
        $Converted = $service.ConvertId($HexId, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::EwsId)
        $idObject = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemId($Converted.UniqueId)
```

Or with Graph using the library:

```
$sourceID = ($sourceId -replace "\+","-") -replace "/","_"
$countToReplace = ($sourceID.ToCharArray() | ? {$_ -eq "="}).Count
$sourceID = $sourceID.TrimEnd("=") + $countToReplace

$body = @{
"inputIds"= @($sourceID)
"sourceIdType"= "entryId"
"targetIdType"= "$TargetFormat"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$ConvertResult =  Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId -UserId $UserId -BodyParameter $body
```

Definitely the result is not an `EWSID`, it looks like that:

1. SourceId: AAAAAB2EAx########################################gAAKDC/7wAAA==
2. TargetId: AAkALg#############################################i8zOVOAAAAAe9FwAA

What am I missing?

Thank you

EDIT:

Following exactly this blog commands, here are the output from the first line ID:

https://www.michev.info/blog/post/2744/converting-item-and-folder-ids-via-the-graph-api

[image]

As we can see, the EWSId does not look at all like a full EWS Id. I even specied IsArchive = $true on the $aiItem.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted in the result anything starting with AAkALg is a immutableId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id the "AAkALg" decodes to a Flag that tells Exchange this which is why it's the same on every request. You should be able to take that Id and then translate it to a ewsid eg

```html
{
    "inputIds": [
        "AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AdRBH-RjqME2dQLFCi6wg0AAIdd8qMwAA"
    ],
    "sourceIdType": "restImmutableEntryId",
    "targetIdType": "ewsId"
}
```

There where previously bugs in Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId so i would probably try using Invoke-MgGraphRequest to see if you get a different result eg

```html
    $ConvertRequest = @"
{
    "inputIds" : [
      "$FolderIdToConvert"
    ],
    "sourceIdType": "entryId",
    "targetIdType": "ewsId"
  }
"@

    $ConvertResult = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method POST -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/translateExchangeIds -Body $ConvertRequest
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue is that even with EWS convertion, I get this immutableId, when the Enum does not even have it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.idformat?view=exchange-ews-api 

Sadly when I run your code snippet, I simply get again the same restImmutableId, even if I try again to convert it to EwsId (so I do EntryId > EwsId, gives me wrongly immutableId, then I do on that result immutableId > EwsId, and still get immutable)

Comment: Sounds like a bug but I can't reproduce it your probably better to log a support call so somebody can have a look at what's really happening. If its a unsupported folder in the Graph (eg an Online Archive or Public folder then that could be a reason)